# Firing selective rules from drool file

Tags: drools

Is it possible to fire rules in drool file by rule names ?
My requirement is, my rule file will contain list of all rules (S). But I've a separate config which contains list of rule names to be fired (A). Note (A) is a subset of (S). At run time, I want to fire only rules with names (A) from (S).

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use AgendaFilters for this.

Here is how you set it:

```
StatelessSession session = ruleBase.newStatelessSesssion();

session.setAgendaFilter( new RuleNameMatches("<regexp to your rule name here>") );
```

This will allow only one rule with the specified name to fire.

In your case you will need to write your own AgendaFilter:

```
public class CustomAgendaFilter extends AgendaFilter{

  private final Set<String> ruleNamesThatAreAllowedToFire;

  public CustomAgendaFilter(Set<String> ruleNamesThatAreAllowedToFire){
    this.ruleNamesThatAreAllowedToFire=ruleNamesThatAreAllowedToFire;
  }

  boolean accept(Activation activation){
    return ruleNamesThatAreAllowedToFire.contains(activation.getRule().getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: In the future version of Drools it should also be possible to use Drools rules to control what rules can fire http://blog.athico.com/2011/08/declarative-agenda-and-control-rules.html

Comment: I'll definitely give a try. This should solve my problem. Thanks.